# Do jquery operations after php operation fails/succeeds

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to php. I wanna open login window after php registration fails "Email already exists"

This is the php code i have

```
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)
   {
        //echo "This Email is already used.";
        //Write code to go back to register window
        header('Location: ../homepage.html');
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                console.log("cdsafcds");
                $(".login_links_login").trigger("click")
                </script>';
   }
```

It is not triggering it. My .js file is separate from .php file. Both .js and .php are in separeate folders.

I read a lot of SO posts all suggested to use `<script>` tag.

Please clear my doubts what i am doing wrong

Comment: are you able to see you log message in console?

Comment: No. But its go to hoimepage.html

Comment: yes because header redirects it to your homepage. you need to write this js code on your homepage.html with some logics..

Comment: Oops.  Can u please tell me the best way to show login window if user tries to register with existing mail

Comment: I have suggest a answer, hope this may help...

Comment: `$ is undefined` you need to include the jquery file properly check that  did u included that ?

Comment: try to include this `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js` in your HTML and check the console.do you get the same  error ?

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper  have it in my html pag `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>` and wher do u want to include it? It's in header and can be accessible from .js file

Comment: ok fine did u try with `jQuery.noConflict()`. ?

Comment: ok :) let me know the result ill help you @GopsAB

Comment: It doesn't show me any error. Page is empty. `jQuery.noConflict();` inserted before triggering click

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing your homepage.html page can handle php request...

```
  header('Location: ../homepage.html?trigger=trigger');
```

in your homepage.html

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['trigger'])) { ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("cdsafcds");
    $(".login_links_login").trigger("click")
 </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Hope this may help you..

Comment: Thanks. I ran it and got `$ is undefined` and replaced that with `document.getElementById("#login_links_login").onclick();` but it says `document.getElementById` is null.

Comment: Seems you didn't had html tag with id `login_links_login` in your homepage

Comment: I have man `<li id="login_links_login" class="login_links_list_ele login_links_login">login</li>`

Comment: try this `document.getElementById('#login_links_login').click();`

Comment: Thats what i said in the first comment itself. Once it said $ is undefined, then i tried this too.

Comment: please fallow @Developing Developer instruction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74186/discussion-between-shravan-shrama-and-gops-ab).